# Resource id #7 when using fopen and fwrite in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to create a download link in PHP so you can download the information in a table. I just started writing it and have run into a snag.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $survey . ";";
 $result = mysql_query($sql)
    or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


 $something = "This is text";
 $myFile = "data.txt";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

 $download_data = "";
 foreach ($row as $k=>$v){
        $download_data .= $k . "=" . $v . "\n";
 }
 fwrite($fh, $download_data);
 fclose($fh);

 echo $download_data;

 ?>
 <a href="data.txt">Download </a>
```

It is just supposed to show something like  Code = 1   Name = John  etc.  When I open the txt file, it simply says Resource id #7.  The weird part is, when I echo $download_data, it looks correctly in the web page.  Is there something special I have to do with fwrite in order to get the whole string into the text file

(Note: I have used both mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc and both have the same result. Also, if I simply declare a variable like  $test = "this is a test";  it works).

Edit:
I have tried commenting out all other code in the script and I get the same result.  Printing $download_data shows the right result, but the text file is still only showing Resource id #7.  I've even tried deleting the txt file and when it is recreated, it does the same thing.

Comment: Can you echo the data you get from your query to the screen?

Comment: Have you omitted any code from your post? I'm not able yet to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Do you mean echoing $row?  If I echo $row['fieldName'] I get the appropriate result.

Comment: There is other code in the script, but it is independent of this.  This is the only part that looks at a table and saves the result in a string.  I'll go back through and make sure I haven't declared a variable twice or something like.  But the code works correctly for you?

Comment: Yeah, if I skip the query part and just assign a junk array to `$row`,  everything starting at `$something = "...";` works as expected when copied directly. So the only difference is that I'm not running the query, but I don't see how the query could cause your problem.

Comment: Seem to have it working.  It doesn't seem to be overwriting the txt file.  So, I must have had an error at one point, and then the was never overwritten.  Is there a way to make it so it always overrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost certainly not showing us the whole picture with your example code.

You are likely writing one of these things to the file:

1. The file handle, `$fh`
2. The result returned from `mysql_query()`

Check you're not mixing up `$result` and `$row`. Or even better, post all of your code.

Comment: I figured it out.  For some reason it is not overwriting the txt file.  So I kept loading the txt file and seeing the Resource id #7.  I changed the name of the txt file in the PHP code, reran it and looked at the new text file and the data was there.  Thanks for the response.